# Using chrome storage API with create-react-app build

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

I'm creating a chrome extension and bootstrapped the project using create-react-app.

**General Problem:**

I want to access `chrome.storage` api in my react app

**Specific Issues:**

I want to be able to use chrome.storage API in my react app to store some settings so I created a script in my `src` directory which tried calling `chrome.storage.sync.set()` and I got
`'chrome' is not defined  no-undef`. I think this is because I need to include the script that makes this call in the manifest. The problem is that I can't include this script from `src` in my manifest because after create-react-app builds my project, `src` gets minified and the file structure is all changed.

The other problem is that create-react-app enforces that I import only from `src` but I need data from `public`, so I can't just make chrome API calls by importing functions from `public`. I know there is an eject feature on create-react-app but I want to maintain the build features that create-react-app gives me.

How can I maintain create-react-app's build feature while getting access to the chrome.storage API from my `src` directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error (`'chrome is not defined no-undef'`) looks like a linting error; the linter that comes with `create-react-app` thinks that `chrome` is undefined because your code never defines it. Little does the linter know, for Chrome extensions, it's a global variable, so *you* don't have to define it.

Try adding `/* global chrome */` to the top of the file(s) that use(s) the `chrome` variable.

Comment: Indeed it was a linter error, now I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined. I checked to make sure my manifest does include the "storage" permission

  
**Edit:**
Interesting, my build environment doesn't have any error and the data seems to be saving correctly but my dev environment shows me the TypeError?

Comment: @Evan the `chrome` variable is only defined when running as a chrome extension. If you run it like a normal webpage, `chrome.storage` will be undefined. (Although Chrome does provide some APIs to normal webpages through the `chrome` object).